# simulate the spiral shape pattern in the matrix

Tags: python

We have a matrix with dimensions n and n (n is an odd number and the user enters it) Write a program to simulate the spiral shape pattern in the matrix.
The pattern is such that starting from the central part of the matrix, whose value is equal to zero, 1 unit to the right and up (odd number) and then 2 We move the unit left and down (even number) and repeat this pattern n-1 times according to whether the number is even or odd. 0 to n-1 to be replaced according to the pattern)

```
6 6 6 6 6 6 5 
6 4 4 4 4 3 5 
6 4 2 2 1 3 5 
6 4 2 0 1 3 5 
6 4 2 3 3 3 5 
6 4 5 5 5 5 5 
6 7 7 7 7 7 7
```

Comment: Can you find a formula or an algorithm for the value_of_element(x,y) ?

Comment: @jeffUK no I can't

Comment: So, assuming you have to draw the spiral out.  Start by generating a list of the sequence (from the center to the end) , then write a function to put that list into the spiral.

Comment: @jeffUK your solution was OK,I'm done.thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all we get a number from user then assuming you have to draw the spiral out. Start by generating a list of the sequence (from the center to the end) , then write a function to put that list into the spiral
bellow link can explain it in more detail.
I change the directions of it's solution.
[newbedev.com/creating-a-spiral-array-in-python](https://newbedev.com/creating-a-spiral-array-in-python)

```
NORTH, S, W, E = (0, 1), (0, -1), (-1, 0), (1, 0)  # directions
turn_left = {NORTH: E, E: S, S: W, W: NORTH}  # old -> new direction


def spiral(width, height, matrixList):
    if width < 1 or height < 1:
        raise ValueError
    x, y = width // 2, height // 2  # start near the center
    dx, dy = NORTH  # initial direction
    matrix = [[None] * width for _ in range(height)]
    count = 0
    while True:
        matrix[y][x] = matrixList[count]  # visit
        count += 1
        # try to turn left
        new_dx, new_dy = turn_left[dx, dy]
        new_x, new_y = x + new_dx, y + new_dy
        if (0 <= new_x < width and 0 <= new_y < height and
                matrix[new_y][new_x] is None):  # can turn left
            x, y = new_x, new_y
            dx, dy = new_dx, new_dy
        else:  # try to move straight
            x, y = x + dx, y + dy
            if not (0 <= x < width and 0 <= y < height):
                return matrix  # nowhere to go


def print_matrix(matrix):
    width = len(str(max(el for row in matrix for el in row if el is not None)))
    fmt = "{:0%dd}" % width
    for row in matrix:
        print(" ".join("_"*width if el is None else fmt.format(el)
              for el in row))




n = int(input())
totalRecord = n*n

numberOfOccurance = 2
numberOfOccuranceIndex = 1

number = 1
index = 1
row = [0]

while index < totalRecord:
    while numberOfOccuranceIndex <= numberOfOccurance:
        row.append(number)
        index += 1
        numberOfOccuranceIndex += 1
        if index >= totalRecord:
            break
    numberOfOccurance += 2
    numberOfOccuranceIndex = 1
    number += 1

print_matrix(spiral(n, n,row))
```

Comment: Credit : https://newbedev.com/creating-a-spiral-array-in-python ?

Comment: the  solution in link is ok,the only difference is "turn right method".here we need to turn left.